# ¿Cómo puedo usar los resultados de una búsqueda en un dataframe como datos de entrada de la siguiente búsqueda en pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Estoy intentando automatizar una cosa. Tengo un dataframe con unas 50000 filas y pocas columnas. Tengo un valor de entrada para buscar en este dataframe en la primera columna y una condición que es siempre igual para otra de las columnas. De los resultados que obtenga, los valores de la segunda columna tienen que ser valores de entrada, es decir, tengo que buscar esos valores de la segunda columna en la primera y que también cumplan con la condición y así sucesivamente hasta que no tenga más coincidencias.

Un trozo del dataframe original es el siguiente:

```
    Start ID    End ID  Start Latitude  Start Longitude End Latitude    End Longitude   Type    Direction   Parity
0   %%bal   BALAP   N480428 E0191611    N480405 E0191500    Permanent   Normal  Even Parity
1   %%BRU   BURAM   N484528 E0105112    N484144 E0105656    CDR1    Normal  Odd Parity
2   ZYG YBN N295624 E1044418    N284753 E1043340    Permanent   Normal  Even Parity
3   %%DIS   %%TEL   N503918 W0010246    N504400 W0005309    Permanent   Arrival Even Parity
4   %%EDH   WSN N533032 E0091349    N532050 E0085229    Permanent   Departure   Even Parity
5   ZYG BHs N295624 E1044418    N303042 E1041201    Permanent   Normal  Even Parity
6   %%BUR   WLD N483728 E0110338    N483446 E0110746    Permanent   Normal  Odd Parity
7   ZYG XYO N295624 E1044418    N281018 E1052512    Permanent   Normal  Odd Parity
8   DOTIS   *BL55   N411207 E0020129    N413125 E0013925    Permanent   Departure   Even Parity
9   *10BC   VNv N411431 E0015416    N411229 E0014133    Permanent   Departure   Even Parity
10  DOTIS   *BL47   N411207 E0020129    N410549 E0014940    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
11  ZYTLO   ANRAT   N385311 E1213049    N383930 E1195724    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
12  BCN.D   DOTIS   N411750 E0020436    N411207 E0020129    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
13  PERAL   NITBA   N411118 E0020219    N410418 E0015908    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
14  BCN.D   *10BC   N411750 E0020436    N411431 E0015416    Permanent   Departure   Even Parity
15  ZYG WFX N295624 E1044418    N303624 E1042930    Permanent   Normal  Even Parity
16  BCN.D   PERAL   N411750 E0020436    N411118 E0020219    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
17  DOTIS   BCN46   N411207 E0020129    N410841 E0014827    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
```

Quiero filtrar este dataframe por la columna Start ID y la columna Direction según las dos variables que tengo ahí definidas: sid y dire. Así, obtener un dataframe nuevo. Lo he hecho así:

```
sid = "BCN.D"
dire = "Departure"

df1 = segments_old[(segments_old["Start ID"] == sid) & (segments_old["Direction"] == dire)]
```

df1 sale:

```
Start ID    End ID  Start Latitude  Start Longitude End Latitude    End Longitude   Type    Direction   Parity
BCN.D   *10BC   N411750 E0020436    N411431 E0015416    Permanent   Departure   Even Parity
BCN.D   DOTIS   N411750 E0020436    N411207 E0020129    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
BCN.D   PERAL   N411750 E0020436    N411118 E0020219    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
```

Ahora tengo que utilizar los valores de la columna End ID de df1 para volver a buscarlos en el dataframe original, segments_old y obtener un nuevo dataframe, df2, que cumpla que los elementos que estaban en la columna End ID de df1 estén en la columna Start ID de df2 y que direction sea igual a la variable dire. Lo he hecho así:

```
lista1 = df1["End ID"].tolist()
df2 = segments_old.loc[(segments_old["Start ID"].isin(lista1))&(segments_old["Direction"] == dire)]
```

Que df2 sería:

```
Start ID    End ID  Start Latitude  Start Longitude End Latitude    End Longitude   Type    Direction   Parity
*10BC   VNv N411431 E0015416    N411229 E0014133    Permanent   Departure   Even Parity
DOTIS   *BL47   N411207 E0020129    N410549 E0014940    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
DOTIS   *BL55   N411207 E0020129    N413125 E0013925    Permanent   Departure   Even Parity
DOTIS   BCN46   N411207 E0020129    N410841 E0014827    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
PERAL   NITBA   N411118 E0020219    N410418 E0015908    Permanent   Departure   Odd Parity
​
```

Así sucesivamente hasta que no haya más coincidencias. Con los df1, df2, df3, etc lo que quiero hacer es concatenarlos, algo como esto:

```
resultado_final = [df1,df2,df3,...]

df_final = pd.concat(resultado_final)
```

Puedo hacerlo así, paso a paso, a mano. Mi duda es si puedo automatizarlo u optimizar el proceso de alguna manera.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, creo que no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer, ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo tal vez con 10-15 filas de tu `dataframe`, el proceso que se necesita hacer mostrando los `dataframes` parciales y el `dataframe` final?

Comment: Espero que esté más claro, muchas gracias, si hacen falta más cambios o más info lo edito las veces que hagan falta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Según entiendo deseas hacer un filtro digamos recursivo y concatenar todos los `dataframes` parciales hasta que se encuentre un `dataframe` vacío.

**Nota:** Dos problemas que creo podrían presentarse (Desconozco tus datos por lo que no se si sea posible con tu `dataframe`). Primero, que el `dataframe` resultante tenga filas repetidas. Segundo que se cree un ciclo infinito si de alguna forma siempre existe un `Start ID` para algún `End ID` en los `dataframes` parciales. Tal vez tengas que considerar una función de "escape" (Que haga `break`) después de X número de iteraciones para evitar el escenario con un ciclo infinito.

Ignorando la nota anterior, cree un `dataframe` (En el archivo "sample.csv") de prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
    Start ID    End ID  Direction
0   ABC         DEF     UNO
1   ABC         GHI     DOS
2   ABC         JKL     UNO
3   DEF         GHI     DOS
4   DEF         JKL     UNO
5   GHI         JKL     DOS
6   JKL         FIN     UNO
```

**Nota:** Cuando tus datos sean muchos o el proceso complicado, es recomendable simplificar la pregunta, por ejemplo crear un `dataframe` de prueba, como en este caso, para que la pregunta y la repuesta se entiendan mejor.

Ahora, el primer paso es filtrar las columnas `Start ID` y `Direction` y para eso utilizas dos variables, pero como este paso se repite en lugar de crear la variable `sid` podríamos utilizar directamente una lista que se sobre escribirá en cada iteración para buscar el `dataframe` resultante

Y podemos concatenar los resultados en un `dataframe` resultante hasta que el `dataframe` parcial esté vacío, en dado caso se terminará el ciclo infinito.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

# Lista con el primer elemento a buscar, esto sustituye tu variable "sid"
lista = ['ABC']
dire = 'UNO'

# Creamos un DataFrame vacío con las columnas del original para concatenar el resultado
dfr = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)

# Ciclo infinito
while True:
    # DataFrame temporal que recibe las filas utilizando los filtros de "lista" y "dire"
    df_temp = df.loc[(df["Start ID"].isin(lista))&(df["Direction"] == dire)]
    
    # Si el DataFrame temporal está vacío entonces terminar el ciclo infinito
    if df_temp.empty:
        break
    
    # Sobreescribir la lista que se utilizará para el filtro
    lista = df_temp['End ID'].tolist()
    
    # Concatenar el DataFrame temporal al DataFrame resultante
    dfr = pd.concat([dfr, df_temp], ignore_index=True)

#Imprimimos el DataFrame resultante
print(dfr)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Start ID    End ID  Direction
0   ABC         DEF     UNO
1   ABC         JKL     UNO
2   DEF         JKL     UNO
3   JKL         FIN     UNO
4   JKL         FIN     UNO
```

**Nota:** Como comenté anteriormente dependiendo de tus datos es posible que existan filas repetidas (Como en el ejemplo genérico que cree) pero no estoy considerando detectar el escenario de obtener un ciclo infinito, eso tendrías que ver si es necesario con tus datos

### Edición

En la respuesta original se concatenan los `dataframes` parciales en cada iteración del `while`, pero esto se puede optimizar al crear una lista que colecte los `dataframes` parciales y utilizar una sola vez `concat`.

Ejemplo optimizado:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')

# Lista con el primer elemento a buscar, esto sustituye tu variable "sid"
lista = ['ABC']
dire = 'UNO'

# Creamos una lista vacía para juntar los DataFrames parciales
dfr = []

# Ciclo infinito
while True:
    # DataFrame temporal que recibe las filas utilizando los filtros de "lista" y "dire"
    df_temp = df.loc[(df["Start ID"].isin(lista))&(df["Direction"] == dire)]
    
    # Si el DataFrame temporal está vacío entonces terminar el ciclo infinito
    if df_temp.empty:
        break
    
    # Sobreescribir la lista que se utilizará para el filtro
    lista = df_temp['End ID'].tolist()
    
    # Concatenar el DataFrame temporal a la lista
    dfr.append(df_temp)

# Concatenar los elementos de la lista y sobre escribir la variable dfr
# para obtener el DataFrame resultante
dfr = pd.concat(dfr, ignore_index=True)

#Imprimimos el DataFrame resultante
print(dfr)
```

El resultado es el mismo que el código anterior pero los tiempos de ejecución para la respuesta original son:

```
CPU times: total: 31.2 ms
Wall time: 6 ms
```

Y de la respuesta optimizada son:

```
CPU times: total: 15.6 ms
Wall time: 5 ms
```

Por lo que la respuesta optimizada terminará el proceso aproximadamente (En el ejemplo genérico es exactamente 50% pero podría variar con un `dataframe` más grande) un 50% más rápido (El tiempo de ejecución se midió con `%%time` desde JupyterLab, para una medición más exacta se podría utilizar `timeit`).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu rápida respuesta! es justo lo que necesitaba, he modificado el dataframe de ejemplo como me pediste y no hay repeticiones. El criterio de parada que sea el del dataframe vacío es perfecto, porque siempre se terminarán los datos. Muchas gracias de nuevo y disculpa si mi pregunta original no era la más adecuada.

Comment: No hay de que, yo creo que no es que la pregunta no era adecuada, más bien es un poco difícil de explicar. Aún no entiendo del todo la meta final o razón de filtrar los datos de esta forma. Tal vez podría hacerse de alguna otra forma sin utilizar `while`, normalmente al utilizar `dataframes` evito utilizar cualquier tipo de ciclos a menos que sean absolutamente el último recurso ya que `pandas` cuenta con funciones que permiten optimizar velocidad y recursos. Tal vez  hay algún método directo pero necesitaría entender mejor el objetivo del proceso. Que bueno que te funcionó. Saludos!

Comment: Cada fila representa un segmento de una aerovía. Cada uno de estos segmentos tiene un proposito concreto. Yo tengo un punto de inicio, y se que a apartir de ahi se concatenan un número finito de segmentos con el mismo proposito, que sería a columna direction. En mi dataframe original tengo todos los segmetnos de europa con todos los propositos posibles.  Y mi objetivo es de toda la maraña de segmentos sacar los que parten de mi punto, el sid inicial que ponia yo. Es esa un poco la explicacion, ejejeje, por arrojarte un poco de luz si se te ocurre otra cosa. tu solucion funciona genial :)

Comment: @JoseCle, edité la respuesta y agregué una solución optimizada, se ejecuta aprox. en la mitad de tiempo que la anterior ya que solo utiliza `concat` una vez.

Comment: muchas gracias!